# load domain specific content

Tags: dns

Let's say I have an app sitting at

```
myapp.com
```

The app has clients or users that are situated here

```
myapp.com/jonny
myapp.com/sally
```

I want to allow users to point their own domain to my server (A record) and load their specific content. No redirects or anything.

```
jonnysapp.com -> myapp.com/jonny
```

So somehow my server needs to detect where the request is coming from and set the client... correct?

update

i'm using a very standard LAMP stack

Answer (score 0):

I solve a similar problem with IIRF (I use IIS, you don't say what you use).

```
RewriteEngine ON
RedirectRule 0

# rewrite the Url to a folder, the host starts WWW 
RewriteCond     %{HTTP_HOST}         ^(www\.)([^\.]+)\.     [I]
RewriteRule     ^/content/(.*)       /content/$1             [L]

RewriteCond     %{HTTP_HOST}         ^(www\.)([^\.]+)\.     [I]
RewriteRule     ^/(.*)$              /content/*2/$1           [L]
```

Each domain has the same A record as you suggest and my set up has each sub site in a sub folder of *content*. e.g.

```
www.jonnysapp.com -> www.myapp.com/content/jonny
```

The reason I've done this is to stop endless loops within the rewriter, without some sort of predictable token to test for the rewriter was rewriting twice (even though I told it to only do it one) and I would have ended up with *myapp.com/jonny/jonny*